# Build my personal "heroku" or "fluxflex" like?

Tags: heroku, paas

I'd like to learn (by doing) how heroku, fluxflex and in general all PaaS work. I mean, how could I build my own "heroku", "fluxflex", GAE... What do I need to know/learn/read? I've seen  appscale, but I'd like to build my own.

Basically what I'd like to do:

- An user gets registered
- He import/upload an app (only allowed frameworks, for example django, ror, node) the app is installed.
- Everything is scalable....

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google search on "Heroku Architecture" and "Openshift Architecture" got me [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/architecture-overview), [this](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/User_Guide/chap-User_Guide-OpenShift_Architecture_Overview.html) respectively. [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/getinvolved) is an Open Source PaaS hosted on Github, and they have a nice blog that describes how CloudFoundry works. Hope that helps. Cheers.